# Image display using PHP and Javascript

Tags: javascript, php

Here is the plan: I will click the submit button then display the image while saving the image on a folder. The problem is that I can't display and save the image.

Here is my code:

```
 <?php
$UPLOADDIR = "images/";
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){
     foreach ($_FILES as $key => $value){
             $image_tmp = $value['tmp_name'];
             $image_type=$value['type'];
             $image = $value['name'];
             $image_file = "{$UPLOADDIR}{$image}";

move_uploaded_file($image_tmp,$image_file)

echo " $(function () {
        $(':file').change(function () {
            if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = imageIsLoaded;
            reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
                     }
                 });
            });

        function imageIsLoaded(e) {
            $('#myImg').attr('src', e.target.result);
        };

        </script> ";




?>
<img id="myImg" src="#" alt="your image" />
```

Thank you for the response

Comment: and what is the question?

Comment: What happens or doesn't happen.  We can't guess your problem.

Comment: It doesn't save and display the image.

Comment: Are you saying you want it to save and display at the same time, or are you saying you want it to save AS it is displaying.

I guess the difference is do you want it to write while it is displaying, or do you want to display it while it is saving. Oh! That clears it up!

Answer (score 0):

I think you miss the `Script opening tag` and some mistakes. try this

```
    <?php
$UPLOADDIR = "images/";
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){
     foreach ($_FILES as $key => $value){
             $image_tmp = $value['tmp_name'];
             $image_type=$value['type'];
             $image = $value['name'];
             $image_file = "{$UPLOADDIR}{$image}";

move_uploaded_file($image_tmp,$image_file);
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>$(function () {
        $(':file').change(function () {
            if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = imageIsLoaded;
            reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
                     }
                 });
            });

        function imageIsLoaded(e) {
            $('#myImg').attr('src', e.target.result);
        };

        </script>";

     }
}
?>
<img id="myImg" src="#" alt="your image" />
```